# HTML5 built-in audio control bar incorrect in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am building a website (with nodejs) and I planned to embed a piece of audio in it using the HTML5 built-in audio class. I wrote this in the html file

```html
<audio id="player" src="test.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" controls=true></audio>
```

Then I run the server and access the website on localhost. The audio did play but I didn't see a full control bar showing up. I see something like this

Incomplete control bar

[image: [1]]

However, if I refresh the page, the control bar did become a complete one with the tracking bar the the volume controller.

Why would this happen? How can I make sure it is a complete one the first time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add the css for width, then the problem will be solved

```
audio { width: 200px; display: block; margin:20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide width and progress to it. Then it will work properly.
You can refer https://m.dotdev.co/how-to-build-an-audio-player-with-html5-and-the-progress-element-487cbbbaebfc for more details.